# Give an $L$-sentence which is true in that structure but false in the other three structures

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Let $L$ be a language with just one binary function symbol $f$ (which will be interpreted as multiplication). For each item in the list of $L$-structures given below, give an $L$-sentence which is true in that structure but false in the other three.

1. $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ with the usual multiplication
2. $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |x|>1\}$ with the usual multiplication
3. $\{x\in \mathbb{C}\mid |x|>1\}$ with the usual multiplication
4. $\{ A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\mid |\det(A)|>1\}$ with matrix multiplication.

My attempt:

For 1., we have $\exists x\forall y (y\cdot x = y)$ (where $x\cdot y = f(x,y)$), i.e. there is a neutral element.

For 4., $\exists x y \neg(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$, since matrix multiplication is not commutative.

I'm looking for distinguishing properties for 2. and 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi_1,\varphi_4$ be your example sentences singling out structures $1$ and $4$ (they work, by the way). Using these, it's enough to find a sentence $\psi$ true in structure $3$ but false in structure $2$ (or vice versa for that matter): structure $2$ is then characterized by $\neg\varphi_1\wedge\neg\varphi_4\wedge\neg\psi$ and structure $3$ is then characterized by $\neg\varphi_1\wedge\neg\varphi_4\wedge\psi$.

So what's something true of $\mathbb{C}_{\vert x\vert>1}$ but not $\mathbb{R}_{\vert x\vert>1}$, and moreover just involves multiplication? *(HINT: Think about square roots ...)*

Comment: Ah, that's a very clever way to restrict the number of structures we need to look at. Thank you! We have $\forall x\exists y (y\cdot y = x)$ in $\mathbb{C}_{|x|>1}$ but not in the other one.

Comment: @Zachary Yup, that's the one I had in mind!